# Differences in the data of 2 properties on the same web site

Tags: google-analytics-4

At the beginning of the year I created the Ga4 property for a client, but I made the mistake of not linking it to the existing Universal Analytics property. In July Analytics automatically created a GA4 property and linked it with the existing Universal Analytics property. Now comparing the data from both properties there is a lot of difference in terms of views and sessions between one property and the other. I don't understand where such a big difference between the data comes from, when in principle they are measuring the same website.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLfRj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zV5L.png)
these are the data for the last 28 days from the same web site

Thank you very much for your help.

I would like to understand well the reason for these differences in the data. and which of the 2 properties is the one with the correct data.
Thank you very much